# Why creating dataset from Encoder.bean create new column based on fonction is*

Tags: java, apache-spark

I dont understand why Encoder don't respect my field but also use function inside my bean to create new column.

I have a Client class, very simple:

```
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private String clientId;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Client(String clientId, String name, int age) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

// getters and setters

   public boolean isLegalAge() {
       return age >= 18;
   }
 }
```

When I create a `Dataset<Client>` I expect to have 3 fields : clientId, name, age but i also get `legalAge` :

```
Dataset<Client> clientsDS = spark.createDataset(
                Arrays.asList(
                        new Client("1", "Alice", 15),
                        new Client("2", "Bob", 18),
                        new Client("3", "Charlie", 20)

                ),
                Encoders.bean(Client.class)
        );
```

show result:

```
+---+--------+--------+-------+
|age|clientId|legalAge|   name|
+---+--------+--------+-------+
| 15|       1|   false|  Alice|
| 18|       2|    true|    Bob|
| 20|       3|    true|Charlie|
+---+--------+--------+-------+
```

I want to use isLegalAge to filter my dataset, not to create a new column. there are a way to change this ? expect changing fonction name or using select/drop ?

if i try to filter the dataset, like this way:

```
Dataset<Client> adultsDS = clientsDS.filter((FilterFunction<Client>) client -> client.getAge() >= 18);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a term
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asTerm(Symbols.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asTerm$(Symbols.scala:211)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asTerm(Symbols.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.findConstructor(ScalaReflection.scala:177)
```

I using java 17 and Spark 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Spark inspects your `Client` class using `reflection`. Since `isLegalAge` is a public getter method, Spark thinks there is an associated field and hence creates a column in the dataframe.

Since you don't want `legalAge` to be a field in your dataframe, just remove it from your `Client` class. You can always filter your dataset to exclude the records where the age is not legal as shown below:

```
Dataset<Client> adultsDS = clientsDS.filter(client -> client.getAge() >= 18);
```